# Reactjs-router-dom and cordova always direct to file:///android_asset/www/index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cordova, react-router

Ok so I've been following this method and attempting to create a `reactjs` application combined with `cordova`, followed every steps on this [link](https://github.com/johnkmzhou/cordova-create-react-app) and it was working fine but when I try to use `react-router-dom` every time I run my app on my mobile it doesn't load the correct component instead it loads a path `file:///android_asset/www/index.html`

So my `App.js` is below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Error from "./components/Error";
import Forgot from "./components/Forgot";
import Main from "./components/Main";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Main} exact />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route path="/Forgot" component={Forgot} />
            <Route component={Error} exact />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And my `index.js` is below importing the `App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./css/main.css";
import App from "./App";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";

const startApp = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
  registerServiceWorker();
};

if (window.cordova) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", startApp, false);
} else {
  startApp();
}
```

I updated my code to use HashRoute instead of BrowserRoute

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import Error from "./components/Error";
import Forgot from "./components/Forgot";
import createHashHistory from "history/createHashHistory";

let history = createHashHistory();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter history={history}>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route path="/Forgot" component={Forgot} />
            <Route component={Error} exact />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here is my component `Register` which generate the error.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Footer from "./Footer";

class Register extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container-login">
          <div className="login-content">
            <div className="login-form">
              <img
                src="img/long logo.png"
                alt="main_log"
                className="img-responsive"
              />

              <div className="input-container">
                <i className="fa fa-user icon" />
                <input
                  className="input-field"
                  type="email"
                  autocomplete="off"
                  placeholder="Full Name"
                  name="email_user"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                <i className="fa fa-envelope icon" />
                <input
                  className="input-field"
                  type="email"
                  autocomplete="off"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  name="email_user"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                <i className="fa fa-key icon" />
                <input
                  className="input-field"
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  name="password"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                <i className="fa fa-key icon" />
                <input
                  className="input-field"
                  type="password"
                  placeholder="Repeat password"
                  name="password"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                <button>Register</button>
              </div>
              <div className="option-section">
                <p>
                  <span>
                    <a href="/forgot">Forgot Password / </a>
                  </span>
                  <span>
                    <a href="/login">Login</a>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Register;
```

Some suggestions said that `cordova` only serve local files and `react-router-dom` must be on a server but I really need to know if this is possible to do? any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have to use a [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) instead of `BrowserRouter`:

```
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

Also here you are some useful links about this theme: [Cordova Apps with React](https://gist.github.com/twilson63/f32d798bc8aaed6a020011f4a1543e20), [Basics of React Router v4](https://itnext.io/basics-of-react-router-v4-336d274fd9e0).

Comment: thanks now it loads the Main component but when I try to click the login link it returned `net:EER_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///login)`

Comment: Are you using the `Link` component from `react-router` ?

Comment: @Sarotobi please share a little bit more code. how do you build links? don't you modify history manually?

Comment: @falinsky i updated my question, i also included the history.

Comment: @Sarotobi what is the version of `react-router` do you use?

Comment: @falinsky my version is `16.4.2`

Comment: @Sarotobi I believe it's the version of your `react` package, not `react-router`

Comment: @falinsky sorry about that its version ^4.3.1 and i am using `react-router-dom`

Comment: @Sarotobi not sure that you should work with the history manually, because the `HashRouter` should do that for you. also please show the components  where you create links clicking on which causes errors.

Comment: @falinsky i update my question and show the component link that generates the error.

Comment: @Sarotobi you should use `Link` or `NavLink` components instead of directly creating `<a></a>` elements. please read more about `Link` component: reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link